# Dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 4; 2 is required

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am using Django 1.8.4, when I tried to run my website on the browser it gave me this error "ValueError at /artists/create
dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 4; 2 is required

```
Request Method:
GET 

Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/artists/create 

Django Version:
1.8.4 

Exception Type:
ValueError 

Exception Value:
dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 4; 2 is required

Python Version:
2.7.10 

Python Path:
['C:\\Users\\Juliks\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\MusicStore\\MusicStore',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Juliks\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\MusicStore\\MusicStore\\env\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Juliks\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\MusicStore\\MusicStore\\env\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Juliks\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\MusicStore\\MusicStore\\env\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\Juliks\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\MusicStore\\MusicStore\\env\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\Juliks\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\MusicStore\\MusicStore\\env\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\Juliks\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\MusicStore\\MusicStore\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\Juliks\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\MusicStore\\MusicStore\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
```

How do I solve the error? Thank you.

Comment: Dunno. Perhaps if you *posted some code* we might have a slight chance of helping? Just a thought.

Comment: some more details related to code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes am using Visual Studio. Here is my code from the views.py --> 
    """
Definition of views.
"""

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime
from app.models import *;


def artistcreate(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    form = ArtistForm();
    return render(request, 'app/create.html', { 'form', form });
elif request.method == "POST":
    form = ArtistForm(request.POST);
    form.save();
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/artists');

def artists(request):
    #return HttpResponse('<html><head><title>Hello Django!     </title></head><body><h1>Hello, Django</h1></body></html>');
artists = Artist.objects.all();
return render_to_response('app/artists.html', { 'artists': artists });

def artistdetails(request, id):
artist = Artist.objects.get(pk = id);
return render_to_response('app/artistdetails.html', {'artist', artist});

def home(request):
"""Renders the home page."""
assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
return render(
    request,
    'app/index.html',
    context_instance = RequestContext(request,
    {
        'title':'Home Page',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
    })
)

def contact(request):
"""Renders the contact page."""
assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
return render(
    request,
    'app/contact.html',
    context_instance = RequestContext(request,
    {
        'title':'Contact',
        'message':'Your contact page.',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
    })
)

def about(request):
"""Renders the about page."""
assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
return render(
    request,
    'app/about.html',
    context_instance = RequestContext(request,
    {
        'title':'About',
        'message':'Your application description page.',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
    })
)
```

Comment: Please *edit the question* and put this code there; but first, fix your indentation, and quote the *relevant parts* only.